# Why is Adelaide Clemens wearing seven layers of clothing for Silent Hill: Revelation?

Tags: character, production, costume, silent-hill-revelation

In *Silent Hill: Revelation*, it appeared to me that Adelaide Clemens was wearing so many layers of clothing.

[image]

Even [IMDb confirmed that](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0938330/trivia?item=tr2624593):

> Heather's on-set outfit consists of a stunning amount of layers. Aside from a presumable set of underwear, she wears a white undershirt and dark purple athletic pants, a paint-splattered tank top and a dark purple rubbery skirt, an orange hoodie, a cream leather vest, an olive green jacket, and a red and black plaid coat, making a total of seven layers.

But what was the reason for making Adelaide wear so much clothing? Is there any out of universe answer for it or is it more of a game homage? Or some production decision?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because it was winter.

The white undershirt and thin-fabric top are both tank-tops. The leggings are to keep her legs warm in the cold. The two overcoats are mostly worn when she is outside.

The red hoodie is a light-weight sweater-like fabric.

Having grown up in a cold region near Lake Ontario with parents who wouldn't let you touch the thermostat, I can say that layering is a good option for regulating temperature.

At left you can see the under-and over-shirts. At right is a capture from a few minutes into the movie where you can see many students bundled up and wearing winter hats.

[image]

Comment: Not that it matters to the movie or script, but the movie was filmed in Toronto, Ontario, Canada by the way. It looks like it was -7C at 9AM on the day they started filming.